# Fancybox overlay color on page load

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm wondering if anyone can help me sort this out. I'm essentially trying to combine this ["Change overlay color and opacity"](http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/) with this ["Launch fancyBox manually on page load"](http://jsfiddle.net/wg4MD/).

The code I currently have is..

```
$.fancybox.open([
{
    height: 500,
    width: 350,
    content : '<a href="#"><img src="http://www.myimageurl.jpg"></a>',

},

], {
padding : 0   
});
```

That seems to work perfectly for the image link to display on page load, but I can't figure out how to get the background/color overlay for everything "behind" the fancybox image. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Just separate each API option with a comma like

```
$.fancybox.open([{
    href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
    title: '1st title'
}, {
    href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
    title: '2nd title'
}, {
    href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
    title: '3rd title'
}], {
    padding: 0, //<== comma here
    // then your overlay color option
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
            }
        }
    } // <== if you want another option after this, don't forget the comma
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3BaXs/)**

---

**EDIT** :

IE9 and below doesn't support CSS `rgba()` so you may need to set a fallback option like :

```
var bk = navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6-9]/i) ? "rgb(58, 42, 45)" : "rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)";
```

The variable above will use the `rgb()` fallback color if the browser is IE9 or below. Then just set the variable within the `helpers` option like :

```
helpers: {
    overlay: {
        css: {
            'background': bk
        }
    }
}
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W3FZP/1/)**

Comment: Hmm...doesn't seem to work. No overlay is displaying. Should I be calling any specific js or css file?

Comment: @Andrea : are you using IE? if so, it doesn't support `rgba` so you may need to set a fallback option. See my edited answer.

Comment: No, I've actually tested in every browser except IE and it's not working =/

Comment: @Andrea : does the http://jsfiddle.net/W3FZP/1/ work? it does for me on every browser